# How does mysql treat nonexistent index values?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a huge table in a  Mysql DB. One column is  a e.g. session id. This field is indexed.

How does mysql react if I search in this table for a non-existent session id? Is the index any help here?

Comment: Is the indexed column numeric?

Comment: No it is a session id it is a varchar(32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the index would help. Without the index MySQL would have to search your entire table to find out that no row matches the query. With the index, it would only search the index (a BTREE), which is much faster.

Comment: That confirms, what I expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It will definitely improve query performance if the column in question is indexed even if the goal is to find out if a value for the column exists in the table or not. It is because indexes, as the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html) [points out](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-indexes.html), are pointers to rows. Index data exist physically separately from the table data. The latter is a largeer, more complex dataset and it's more costly to consult then index data.

When the query `SELECT id FROM table where id = 'abc123'` is executed, a full table scan will be performed without an index on `id` even if the it yields no result, but the table data will not be consulted at all if `id` is indexed because only the index data is scanned and that's enough to return a null result.